# How to call Alloy from C++?

Tags: c++, alloy

I have a project in C++, and now I need to call Alloy from it to generate a model. I know that it is possible in Java, I am wondering if it is possible in C++ as well.

Comment: This thing seems to be a Java library. The simplest approach would be to write a Java program that understands some arguments passed to `main` and call it from C++ with `system`. Other than that, the question is too broad.

Answer (score 0):

Alloy is written in Java and built into a jar. It only has a [Java API](http://alloy.mit.edu/alloy/documentation/alloy-api/index.html), thus it offers no direct way of using Alloy from a C++ application. (Note that if you need only to generate a model, you can always write your model in a textual form to a file.)

As mentioned in the comments to your question, one possibility is to write a separate "thin layer" application in Java with which you C++ application would communicate.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Is there a system call to run Alloy on an instance? I used "Alloy", but it opened the program, instead of running it on the instance.

Comment: There is no way of running Alloy besides running it as IDE (that is, as a GUI application). Thus, the only immediate alternative is to write a new Java application that uses Alloy's Java API.